# Convert comma separated character to comma separated integer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to convert the string `"1,2,3,4"` to `1,2,3,4` in jQuery/JavaScript. How can I convert this? Can I use any built in function for the same ?

Comment: What is the data type of `1,2,3,4`? It's not valid JavaScript.

Comment: [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string back to an `array` and convert the elements to a number.

Comment: @ Krishna. Yes it is but comma separated integers.

Comment: @ARUNP.S: Your `"1,2,3,4"` already **is** comma-separated integers. The only way you can have "comma separated integers" in JavaScript is inside a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) makes it easy.

```
var str = "1,2,3,4";
var numbers = JSON.parse("[" + str + "]");
console.log(numbers);
```

Comment: If JSON is supported by the browser.

Comment: @Xotic750 http://caniuse.com/json IE8+ and all modern browsers

Comment: Oh that's just evil. +1

Comment: Speaking of evil: `Function("return [" + str + "];")()` :P

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're looking for `String#split`:

```
var a = "1,2,3,4".split(",");
```

`a` is now an array containing strings with one digit. If you want *numbers*, you have to convert them:

```
var a = "1,2,3,4".split(",").map(Number);
```

That uses `split` to create an array, then `Array#map` to pass each entry through the `Number` function, which will convert them into numbers. Alternately, if you want to be absolutely sure to be using base 10 (e.g., "0x10" doesn't end up being 16):

```
var a = "1,2,3,4".split(",").map(function(entry) {
    return parseInt(entry, 10);
});
```

Note that `Array#map` is from ES5. Modern browsers have it, older ones may need a shim. If you need to support them, search for "ES5 shim" or "Array map polyfill," you'll find one. Beware that some are of higher quality than others.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "1,2,3,4";
var output = str.match(/[^\s,]/g);
for (var i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
    output[i] = parseInt(output[i]);
}
```